# Recognising generic type parameter brackets

Tags: c#, generics, antlr, lexer

I'm currently working on a language that is a superset of C#. However, I'm having trouble trying to get the lexer to recognise opening and closing generic type brackets, specifically open type expressions that are used in like `typeof()` expressions, e.g. `typeof(List<List<>>)`.

If I have three rules:

```
OpenTriangleBracket
    :    '<'
    ;

CloseTriangleBracket
    :    '>'
    ;

Symbol
    :    ('>' | '<')+
    ;
```

Part (1) of the below type is recognised properly (`<`). However, part (2) is recognised as a symbol (`<>>`). Normally, this would be desirable behaviour. If it's a type, I want it to be recognised as its three separate parts (`<`, `>`, `>`).

```
List<List<>>
    v    ^v^
    1     2
```

How could I get it to recognise it as such? As I'm writing the parser part of it myself, I have complete control over how it can be implemented.

Comment: You could use [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn) rather than lexing it yourself.  If you do that, it will parse and analyze the entire codebase for you, and provide powerful tools for you to analyze it further, or add on to it.  Also, is this for a "real" production app, or is this just a toy project for your own experiences?

Comment: Actually it's a whole new language! It's just using the same declarations of generic types. This is going to be a production language, yes.

Comment: So it's going to do everything possible in C# *and* more? Wow. Anyway, IMO, the lexer should just recognize `'<'` or `'>'`, and the parser should make sense of them (see if they're part of generic type parameters, or of a relational expression).

Comment: The trouble I'm having Bart is that `<>>` is being recognised as a single token, I'm having trouble splitting it up! And I'm leaving out COM interop :) Although with the plugin system it will be possible to add it back in.

Comment: @Darkzaelus, that is because `Symbol` shouldn't be in your lexer. Have a look at this C# 4.0 grammar: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1335792765749/CSharp_4.0_grammar.zip

Comment: Hi Bart, my language handles symbols and IDs a bit like scala; accept anything unless it's a reserved symbol. The symbol declaration above is just used for testing purposes for this question. Also I've been using that grammar for a few hints :)

Comment: Ah, okay. Anyway, to summarize (in case I haven't hammered enough on it *:)* ): the rule `Symbol : ('>' | '<')+;` is messing it up for you, and should be removed entirely from the lexer, IMO.

Comment: Hi Bart, I agree :) However, in all of the other circumstances (e.g. infix expressions), it should be in there. It's a lot more complicated in my actual grammar, includes a few unicode character groups. What I did in the end was abstract the `LT()` and `Consume()` methods, split the symbol into it's component parts, put them in a queue and consume those fake tokens instead! If you're interested in it, I'll be releasing it open source in a few months when I have something to show for it.

Comment: You forgot to mention a link to your (presumably already released) code.